# Return a value from a function called in while loop

Tags: function, python-2.7, while-loop

The point is to guess a random number choosen from an interval of integers and do it within a fixed numbers of attempts.

The `main` function asks the upper limit of the interval and the number of guesses the user can give. The core function then should return the guessed value so when the number is right the function should terminate immediately.

I put some print statement while debugging and I understood that the `y` value is not returned to the `while` statement from the `core` function.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def main():
    from random import choice
    p = input("choose upper limit: ")
    t = input("how many attempts: ")
    pool = range(p+1)
    x = choice(pool)
    i = 1
    while ((x != y) and (i < t)):
        core(x,y)
        i += 1

def core(x,y):
    y = input("choose a number: ")
    if y == x:
        print("You gussed the right number!")
        return y
    elif y > x:
        print("The number is lower, try again")
        return y
    else:
        print("The number is higher, try again")
        return y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to assign the *return value of `core`* back to the local `y` variable, it's not passed by reference:

```
y = core(x)
```

You'll also need to set `y` before you go into the loop. Local variables in functions are not available in other functions.

As a result, you don't need to pass `y` to `core(x)` at all:

```
def core(x):
    y = input("choose a number: ")
    if y == x:
        print("You gussed the right number!")
        return y
    elif y > x:
        print("The number is lower, try again")
        return y
    else:
        print("The number is higher, try again")
        return y
```

and the loop becomes:

```
y = None
while (x != y) and (i < t):
    y = core(x)
    i += 1
```

It doesn't much matter *what* you set `y` to in the `main()` function to start with, as long as it'll never be equal to `x` before the user has made a guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
y = -1
while ((x != y) and (i < t)):
    y = core(x,y)
    i += 1
```

You "initialize" y before the loop. Inside the loop you set y equal to the result of core() function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can understand the mistake now.